# Navigation Component with all fragments or some activities?

Tags: android, navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm making an app that at its core has a bottom navigation view. The concern arises when I need to navigate to a page that should not have nor show a bottom navigation view. If I use a fragment wouldn't the bottom navigation still show up since it's declared in the main activity's xml:

Main Activity XML

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

My question is: Should I use a new activity with its own NavHostFragment and graph? Or maybe use nested navigation and keep using fragments? How would I hide the bottom navigation view if I do go with the latter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [Listen for navigation events documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#listen_for_navigation_events):

> As an example, you might have common UI elements that you intend to show in some areas of your app while hiding them in others. Using your own `OnDestinationChangedListener`, you can selectively show or hide these UI elements based on the target destination

So yes, you can selectively show or hide elements of your activity's UI, such as your `BottomNavigationView` when you move to certain destinations:

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
    if(destination.id == R.id.full_screen_destination) {
        nav_view.visibility = View.GONE
    } else {
        nav_view.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }
}
```

Comment: I missed that section when reading the docs. Thank you for this though! Seems they really thought of everything.